# Django 1.10 unable to get variable into the context

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm working on a django site (my first) and I was trying to add a form to the context.  I wasn't able to see the variable in my template, so I simplified to a string variable, and still no result.  I'm not entirely clear on what I'm doing wrong so I was hoping to get some help.

Here's the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import  render
from django.http import  HttpResponse
from django.template.context import RequestContext

from forms import LoginForm

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Index page for COMPANY portal")

def login(request):

    lFormContext = RequestContext(request,{'mystring' : 'mystring'})
    return render(request, 'login.html',  lFormContext )
```

and here's the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load debug_tags %}


{% block container %}
    <div class="content">

        {% variables %}

        {% if form.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <p><strong>{% trans "Oh snap!" %}</strong> {% trans "Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields are case-sensitive." %}</p>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">{% csrf_token %}
            <legend><span class="col-sm-offset-1">{% trans 'Log in' %}</span></legend>
            {% for field in form.fields %}
                <p>iterating over form.fields </p>
                {% include 'registration/form_field.html' %}
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{% trans 'Log in' %}</button>
                  &nbsp;<button type="reset" class="btn">{% trans 'Cancel' %}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <p><a href="{% url 'resetPassword' %}">{% trans "Reset my password" %}</a></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $(".alert-message").alert();
                $('#mainForm').submit(function(){
                    $('#submit').button('loading');
                })
            });
            document.forms[1].elements[2].focus();
        </script>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I would expect the output from {% variables %} to show some reference to the 'mystring' that I added in the view, but there's no extra variable added.  I somewhat need to figure this out.

Here's the output from {% variables %}

> ['DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS', 'False', 'None', 'True', 'block',
>   u'csrf_token', 'messages', 'perms', u'request', 'user', u'view']

I'm not sure what's exactly wrong -- I'm adding to the context dictionary properly.  Is there a setting that I could be missing?  This seems pretty basic.

Here is my TEMPLATES setting:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/portal/templates/portal'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`render` takes a dict, not a RequestContext; it generates the RequestContext itself.

```
def login(request):
    lFormContext = {'mystring' : 'mystring'}
    return render(request, 'login.html',  lFormContext)
```

Comment: Daniel, thanks for answering.  I had tried your suggestion, changing to a dict, but still don't see the variable in the template.  I also described the request object within the template but don't see the variable there.  I would think a setting is missing or incorrect.  Could that be the case?  TIA.  Bob

Comment: No, there are no settings involved. Are you sure that is the right view? What URL are you using, and what do your urls.py look like? Are there any other views that render that template? (To be honest, your original code would have given a TypeError anyway.)

Comment: It's the only view that I've created so far:  <domain>/portal/accounts/login and here's the corresponding line from urls.py:
url(r'^accounts/login$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="login.html"), name='login'),

Comment: The problem was in my urls.py file....thanks for pointing me in the right direction Daniel Roseman!